# Implementing an "application logic" layer in CodeIgniter

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, model, logic

In Asp.NET applications, there is a service layer that stands between the repositories and the controllers, so that different parts of the application can make use of the same logic, without any inconsistencies when one part changes.

For example, in CodeIgniter, if there is a part of the application that responds to REST API calls, I'd need to implement the same logic used in the Account controller for authentication. If there were something like UserService, that could be so easy.

What I'm asking is, do you think that this approach makes sense with CodeIgniter, if there is already a built functionality that covers that and if not, what would be the best way? Should I <strike>use libraries</strike> create my libraries which act like a service layer? Should I just put everything into models (probably not)? Or, wouldn't CodeIgniter be suited for apps which require that kind of complexity at all?

I need your insight on this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeIgniter can handle this perfectly. The idea is that the Controller is the main part of a request where logic is handled right? So a user hits a URL, they go to a controller and the controller decides wether to show them data, redirect them somewhere or tell them to shove off.

To share logic throughout your application you can create a MY_Controller (extending the main CI_Controller class) then this will be run for every controller. If you want to be more specific and have different kinds of controller loading different base controllers then you can.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: That is a great idea... Base controllers for specific sets of controllers which actually respond to requests. The problem would be, what if a logic needs to be shared between those two base controllers? As multiple inheritance isn't possible, is it acceptable to make a BASE-Base controller (!) which gets cluttered with everything that needs to be shared between two or more?

Comment: My article displays a simple separation of all (MY_Controller) Admin (Admin_Controller) and frontend (Public_Controller) but any combination is just as acceptable. Just name them whatever you like. MY_Controller = BASE anyway.

Comment: Like @EgeÖzcan I have the same problem I can't load two controllers. I if I want to make a simple login, I want some place a controller (logic layer) to load something like LogEventsController and apply some command like $this->LogEventsController->SaveLog($userData, 'user enter to app'); This can't to be done, some books suggest put it in a session variable and redirect to that second control but is useless.

Comment: I think need to add some code inside model folder, only to have a space to do business logic and load it freely. but I cant think of another idea of how to do it. And inherit all it will make heavier the app and finish with the charm of codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parent controller to stay DRY. PHP doesn't support any kind of mixins or multiple inheritance, though, so being able to add generic functionality to one or more of your controllers isn't quite as easy.

As far as authentication goes, allegedly this is one of the things that EllisLabs et al are working on for CodeIgniter 2.0 right now. They've mentioned that it's a pretty difficult task, and I think that is testament more to the fact that PHP sucks as a dynamic language than it does that CodeIgniter isn't suited to this sort of thing.

If you're not married to PHP/CI yet, thumbing through what Ruby on Rails offers might be of benefit. All this authentication is handled with mixins and metaprogramming in a really elegant and flexible way.

Comment: Looks to me like Ege was talking more about a way to implement authentication logic throughout his application, not looking for a specific authentication library. There are plenty of those around already. As for Auth in CodeIgniter 2.0.x we have not actually started anything, just accepted that it will go in at some point.

Comment: Includes but definitely not limited to authentication. I'm just searching for the best place to put my validation and application logic.

Comment: @Phil Sturgeon: Thanks for clarification on the Auth. I don't want to be doling out bad information. :)